# EntityFramework doesn't include where clause in sent query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have an internationalized database with lets say a `Collection` table, an `i18n` table and a `translation` table.

`collection` name field contains a GUID from the `i18n` table and `translation` table contains a list of translations for each locale.

Here is the code I use in C#:

```
var ctx = new CollectEntities();
var colls = ctx.collections.Include(x => x.i18n);

foreach(var c in colls)
{
    var t = c.i18n.translations.Where(x => x.locale_id == "fr").FirstOrDefault();
    MessageBox.Show(t.trans_text);
}
```

And here are the generated SQL queries:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[coll_id] AS [coll_id], 
    [Extent1].[coll_name] AS [coll_name], 
    [Extent2].[i18n_id] AS [i18n_id], 
    [Extent2].[i18n_default] AS [i18n_default]
    FROM  [dbo].[collection] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[i18n] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[coll_name] = [Extent2].[i18n_id]
-- Executing at 20/11/2019 11:39:12 +01:00
-- Completed in 17 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[trans_id] AS [trans_id], 
    [Extent1].[i18n_id] AS [i18n_id], 
    [Extent1].[locale_id] AS [locale_id], 
    [Extent1].[trans_text] AS [trans_text]
    FROM [dbo].[translation] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[i18n_id] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '929ba17e-c6c0-43ff-a8bc-6efa950fa03d' (Type = Guid, IsNullable = false)
```

This is a waste of time and traffic if I have 50 translations available. Why isn't it generating:

```
    WHERE [Extent1].[i18n_id] = @EntityKeyValue1 AND [Extent1].[locale_id] = @the_locale_I_want
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: I simplified the code for the purpose of this question. I know as presented, it would make sense to directly fetch a list of the trans_text field.

But "in real world", each `translation` object would at least have two properties (text and picture), and each `collection` object would have other needed properties. So it would still be needed to iterate thru `collections`. Oh, and translation would always exist.

What I would like to achieve, is to retrieve all collections with the appropriate translation already loaded with one query.

Let me add an example to illustrate:
An 'old style' SQL Query without EF would be something like:

```
SELECT collection.*, i18n.*, translation.*
FROM collection
    INNER JOIN i18n ON i18n.i18n_id=collection.coll_name
    LEFT OUTER JOIN translation ON translation.i18n_id=i18n.i18n_id
        AND translation.locale_id = 'fr'
```

And code to consume would be:

```
var ctx = new CollectEntities();
var colls = ctx.collections.Include(x => x.i18n)[.something to catch translation];

foreach(var c in colls)
{
    var t = c.i18n.translations.Where(x => x.locale_id == "fr").FirstOrDefault();
    MessageBox.Show($"{c.coll_id}, price={c.coll_price}, name is {t?.trans_text ?? c.i18n.i18n_defaulttext}, picture file is {t?.trans_picturefilename}");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on other answers, I found a solution that keeps the original objects in the query result, in order to keep the advantage of getting the new fields available on future EF model sync from database:

```
var ctx = new CollectEntities();

var colls = ctx.collections
    .Select(x => new { Obj = x, x.i18n, trans = x.i18n.translations.Where(t => t.locale_id == "fr").FirstOrDefault() });

foreach (var c in colls2)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{c.Obj.coll_id}: {c.trans?.trans_text ?? c.Obj.i18n.i18n_default}");
}
```

That way, the `Obj` property contains the original `collection` object, and `trans` contains the `translation` object, if applicable. I had to add `x.i18n` to the resulting object to force EF to load the i18n navigation property, because the `Select` method returning a new object type cancels the `Include` directives.

Answer (score 2):

You are enumerating the collections query on the loop and then getting a translation for each instance. You can accomplish the same in one query.

```
var ctx = new CollectooEntities();
var dto = ctx.collections.Select(x => new {
        coll_id = x.coll_id,
        coll_price = x.coll_price,
        i18n_defaulttext = x.i18n.i18n_defaulttext,
        trans = x.i18n.translations
            .Where(t => t.locale_id == "fr")
            .Select(t => new { trans_text, trans_picturefilename })
            .FirstOrDefault()
    });

foreach(var c in dto)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{c.coll_id}, price={c.coll_price}, name is {c.trans?.trans_text ?? c.i18n_defaulttext}, picture file is {c.trans?.trans_picturefilename}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I simplified for the actual question, each translation would have 2 properties (text and picture), and the collection item would have other properties that I would need to address. So I would need to iterate thru collections and eventually have the needed translation already loaded, is it possible?

Comment: I projected just one property but you can project all properties you need, from either collection, i18n or translation objects. I see you modified the question. I will edit my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but this looses the fact that if I add fields in the table, then sync EF Model against it, I will have to manually go to all my code places to add the new fields to the select statement, because I'm not returning the "collection" object itself.

Comment: Ideally you should read only what you need from the database. If your requirements change so would the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the collection as `IQueryable` so then it will execute the query on your server side including your added filters.

i.e. With the inclusion of

`Where(x => x.locale_id == "fr").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Actually variable `colls`, even if I used `var`, is showing as IQueryable<collection>.

Comment: What about `translations` in i18n?

Comment: Oh yes it is an ICollection<translation>. Should I cast this one to IQueryable<translation>? EDIT: just tested, cannot be casted.

Answer (score 0):

## The include way

You need use `Query()` here.

[Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#applying-filters-when-explicitly-loading-related-entities):

> **Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities**
>
> The Query method provides access to the underlying query that Entity Framework will use when loading related entities. You can then use LINQ to apply filters to the query before executing it with a call to a LINQ extension method such as ToList, Load, etc. The Query method can be used with both reference and collection navigation properties but is most useful for collections where it can be used to load only part of the collection. For example:
>
> ```
> using (var context = new BloggingContext())
> {
>     var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);
>
>     // Load the posts with the 'entity-framework' tag related to a given blog.
>     context.Entry(blog)
>            .Collection(b => b.Posts)
>            .Query()
>            .Where(p => p.Tags.Contains("entity-framework"))
>            .Load();
> ```

## No include way

You don't seem to be filtering for any specific collection so why not just load the translations directly?

```
forach( t in ctx.translations.Where(x => x.locale_id == "fr"))
         MessageBox.Show(t.trans_text);
```

If you want to add a filter you could

```
var t = ctx.translations.Where(x => x.locale_id == "fr" && i18n_id = ...))
MessageBox.Show(t.trans_text);
```

Comment: Why can't he make the collection as IQueryable itself?